# Gather resource usage by process in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, memory-leaks, monitoring, prometheus, grafana

I am searching for a tool similar to Prometheus + Grafana that gather and record resource usage especially memory usage by process-ID or process-name.

We have two components that are running different processes and they have memory leak and I want to find which process is leaking.

This is from Weave Scope and it shows all the processes of each pod and their resource usage but it is just live, I want something similar but storing it over time like a Prometheus graph.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution where you can monitor it on a container level based on Zabbix.

[Dockbix Agent XXL](https://github.com/monitoringartist/dockbix-agent-xxl) is an agent for [Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/) capable to monitor all Docker containers on your host.

You need to deploy it on all nodes and it will collect data of your containers and sent it to your Zabbix Server.

[image]

> No classic rpm/deb package installation or Zabbix module compilation.
>   Just start the dockbix-agent-xxl container and Docker container
>   metrics will be collected from the Docker daemon API or cgroups.